# How to, using PHP, get the host's hardware profile?

Tags: php, hardware, host

How to, using PHP, get the host's hardware profile?

Comment: Define "hardware profile". What info is that supposed to include exactly? What OS is this on?

Comment: @Eddsstudio: not funny at all. Main part of this question is about getting the data. Hashing function isn't important.

Comment: -1 because you are beginning to build a history of asking poor, unclear questions with zero context and without ever clarifying anything, thus sending people on wild goose chases and wasting everyone's time.

Comment: @Pekka: "hardware profile" = enough info about server's hardware to ensure that my script only runs on that particular host. It's on Linux.

Comment: @Bronislaw but it is an extremely complex topic what defines "enough info" in this context. What if the host gets new RAM? A new mainboard? You can't check too much because the software would deactivate at the slightest change. You can't check too little, because your software could be easily copied to another server. Where do you draw the line? This is non-trivial, and huge companies like Microsoft have gone through great lengths to get this working half-way okay. If you want to copy protect PHP scripts, consider other options like encoding

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter for me, if e.g. it gets new RAM or anything - I want to get info about it's hardware profile at the time the code starts. And no, it's not for protection of the script / licensing.

Comment: @Bronislaw why not use an easier identifier then, like the server's host name or IP address?

Comment: @Bronislaw you will need to watch your language if you want to have a future on this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to use [shell_exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) to cat some of the data from the various /proc/* files that are commonly used on Linux/Unix systems, the key ones probably being:

- /proc/cpuinfo
- /proc/meminfo

For example:

```
echo shell_exec('cat /proc/cpuinfo/');
```